# Route Local Network through Server?

Tags: linux, networking, internet, tcpip

This may or may not be an easy question, as I'm somewhat uninformed in the networking side of computer science.

I own a rented server with a static ip address. Is there a way that I can forward requests from it to my computer to setup a LAN network of sorts over the internet.

Specifically, there is a program I would like to use that requires LAN (you enter an IP to connect to). Is it possible to setup my server in a way that users could connect to my server's ip, which would then forward it to my home computer (I'm fine with setting up my home computer with programs that would allow this) that could host?

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your hosted server has SSH shell access then you could use putty and SSH tunnels.

May take some finagling but you can get it pretty much setup to forward traffic and too and fro.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Comment: Yes, in this case you want "Remote port forwarding", make sure to enable access for other hosts. This will only work for TCP, and fail for UDP-based protocols (such as games or voip)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, an easy route is SSH port forwarding, assuming you only need TCP. There may also be other ways to do this, without going trough your server.

If your program allows you to enter an IP to connect to, can't they directly enter your public IP address ? (if you are behind NAT, you'll first have to setup port forwarding on your device).

Can your program accept DNS names instead of numerical adresses ? (many programs can.) If you have a dynamic address at home, you can use some dynamic dns provider such as dyndns to get a fixed hostname.

Since you have your own static address, you could also buy a domain and run your own dynamic DNS service.